# can't access swift method from objective-c interface

Tags: objective-c, swift

I need to call my swift method from an Objective-C interface, however I keep getting `Use of undeclared identifier 'MySwiftClass'`.

My swift class works fine on other places. I have `#import "myApp-Swift.h"` in my objc file and `@objc` before my swift class. I am not really good with Objective-C, so any help would be really appreciated.

```
@interface myInterface ()
-(void) logger:(NSArray<MyArray*>*) events withCallback:(void (^)(NSError*)) callback;
@end


@implementation myInterface
-(void) logger:(NSArray<MyArray*>*) events withCallback:(void (^)(NSError*)) callback{
..
[MySwiftClass mySwiftMethod]
..
}

@end
```

My swift class:

```
import Foundation

@objcMembers
public class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
@objc
class func mySwiftMethod(){
}
}
```

Comment: What, if any, `MySwiftClass` stuff ended up in your `myApp-Swift.h`? And, does `MySwiftClass` work fine in other places; and, why did you write "My swift class" which is very confusing???

Comment: Yes, I can call this from myappdelegate which is in `objective-c`. I don't understand your last question! If you are talking about the naming, these are just random name I chose for this post, my code is different.

Comment: So, you can call the exact same code like `[MySwiftClass mySwiftMethod]` from the app delegate, but not from another Obj-C file? That would be weird. Did you try things like clean, delete derived data, restart Xcode, ...? Is all code part of the same module/target and is it a simple app without frameworks? I suggest to show more realistic code (and please correct the formatting).

Comment: It's not a simple app actually, and I cannot share the code :(. I also did clean, delete derived data, restart Xcode.

Comment: Well, then it's a matter of sorting out in what module the Swift code is, possibly adding the `myApp-Swift.h` to an umbrella header. You then probably need an `@import ModuleThatHasSwiftCode;` instead. Without knowing the exact structure I can only give these general suggestions.

Comment: Did you import the module, using `@import MySwiftClass` ??? You say that it works in some places and others no. So it could be related to modules